# Function variable is undefined after definition

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code

```
var Point = function (startX, startY) {
  var x = startX
  var y = startY
}

function somefunc (data) {
    var newPoint = new Point(data.x, data.y);
    console.log(data.x + ":" + data.y);
    console.log(newPoint.x + ":" + newPoint.y);
}
```

And I get in console

```
0:0
undefined:undefined
```

Why newPoint values aren't assigned?

Comment: variables are NOT properties of the context. Use `this` to access the context and assign properties to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `var` declaration with `this` access. You need to attach *properties* to the current object which will be created via `new`. Without `this` they are created when you call the function and removed after function call.

```js
var Point = function (startX, startY) {
  this.x = startX;
  this.y = startY;
}

function somefunc (data) {
    var newPoint = new Point(data.x, data.y);
    console.log(data.x + ":" + data.y);
    console.log(newPoint.x + ":" + newPoint.y);
}

somefunc({x: 1, y: 1});
```

If you use function as an object creator, **ES6** provides special keyword - `class`, which is *OOP* friendly way to create objects

```js
class Point {
  constructor(startX, startY) {
     this.x = startX;
     this.y = startY;
  }
}

function somefunc (data) {
    var newPoint = new Point(data.x, data.y);
    console.log(data.x + ":" + data.y);
    console.log(newPoint.x + ":" + newPoint.y);
}

somefunc({x: 1, y: 1});
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascripts inheritance might be confusing at first. When you call a function with `new`, it creates a new object, and the special `this` variable will refer to that object. The function will then automatically return `this`. So to set properties of that object, you need to assign them to `this`, as the variables of the constructor function are not exposed in any way:

```
function Point(x, y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
```

This behaves equal to:

```
function Point(x, y){
  var context = {};

  context.x = x;
  context.y = y;

  return context;
}
```

However you could also use javascripts `class` syntax which might look a bit more logical:

```
class Point {
  constructor(stattX, startY){
    this.x = startX;
    this.y = startY;
  }
  // class methods here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a new variable 'x' and 'y' inside Point which will be only accessible inside the function as declaring variable like this makes it local variable. You can use closure for the same so that each instance you create of the point you have value stored in it.

```
var Point = function (startX, startY) {
  return {
     x: startX,
     y: startY
  }
}



var newPoint1 = new Point(10, 20);
var newPoint2 = new Point(20, 10);

console.log(newPoint2.x + ":" + newPoint2.y);
console.log(newPoint2.x + ":" + newPoint2.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the magic of `new` keyword.

Generally when ever we create an object, we do not return explicitly an object from the function when you use new keyword, as it does for us.

```
var Point = function (startX, startY) {
  var obj = {}  // common part
  obj.x = startX;
  obj.y = startY;
  return obj //common part
}
```

we call it without `new` keyword as below and the work is done

```
var newPoint = Point(data.x, data.y);
console.log(newPoint.x + ":" + newPoint.y);
```

When ever we create a constructor function we are overdoing as the object declaration and return part are common in every function

i.e.,

```
var obj = {}
return obj
```

So the new keyword provide  you with the boilerplate of declaring the object and returning it implicitly.

```
var Point = function (startX, startY) {
  var this = {}  // implicit declraration by new keyword
  this.x = startX;
  this.y = startY;
  return this  //implicit return by new keyword
}
```

So you must bind your variables to this, which you want to return.